# IIS web farm framework Load balancing vs classic load balancing

Tags: iis-7, asp.net, .net, iis

As asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28562581/iis-web-farm-framework-load-balancing-vs-classic-load-balancing?noredirect=1#comment45437542_28562581),
I'm currently having a look at the IIS Web Farm Framework, but i'm concerned about performance.

Is there an important difference between a classic Load Balancer, and the WFF load balancing ? Would it fit for a high trafic website (millions of requests each month) ? I searched the web for articles on WFF, but none seemed to make a benchmark or comparison with a classic load balancer.

And would there be Bandwith issues?

Thanks